# Is there any file limit in php ZipArchive?

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I have the following problem, I have an array with several Amazon S3 links referring to .xml files.

I then pass these files through a forach and place them using php's ZipArchive addFromString.

The problem is that for some reason it always adds approximately 15 thousand files and my client has 31 thousand files.

It does not generate an error that terminates the execution of my script.

```
    foreach(json_decode($res->getBody()) as $xml){

        $caminhoArquivo = parse_url($xml, PHP_URL_PATH);
        $name = basename(urldecode($caminhoArquivo));
        

        $request = new Request('GET', $xml);
        
        try {

            $content = $client->sendAsync($request)->wait();

        }catch(Exception $e){

            continue;
        }

        $zip->addFromString($pathe.$name, $content->getBody())
    }
```

I used:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

set_time_limit(0);

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Comment: How many iterations of the loop are you getting? Perhaps the initial response in $res is paginated. Also note that if you catch an exception on the async request, you're just silently skipping that record. At least spit out an error message or something so that you know what's happening.

Comment: Can you try using `addFile();` instead of `addFromString();` ? It is known to consume much less memory. You could also try to `exec();` your zip command line

Comment: What's the size of the generated zip?